# .htaccess hotlink protection redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

my htaccess file contains the following

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule view.php - [F]
```

Here if view.php requested from refer other than localhost will show forbidden.
The view.php file is requested as view.php?id=44,  so I need to redirect the visitor to download.php?id=46 rather that forbidden page is shown.

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? Your "question" at this moments looks like a task we have to accomplish.

Comment: Yes I have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: what didn't work? If I put "RewriteRule redirect" into google I see tons of relevant info. Do you know about google.com?

Comment: Thank you, I felt now that Google is useful. I don't know how I can develop any thing without knowing Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^view/([^/.]+)/?$ download/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([^/.]+)/?$ download.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view/([^/.]+)/?$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now your URLs will be view/44 instead view.php?id=44 and download/44 instead of download.php?id=44

Comment: kudos to answering a question I read 5 times and still don't understand what is being asked.